# Make Http Post request with new password rest-client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, http, rest

I'm trying to change a password over a rest interface with rest-client.

With the instructions shown below  a basic authentication is required.
I think I implemented the basic authentication right in my request.  **My problem is that I don't know how I should set a new Password in the requestBody**

The instructions, example:

```
URL:    {base_url}/accounts/{uid}/password

HTTP-Method:    POST

Request Body:   text/plain

Response Body:  text/plain

HTTP Status Code:   201, 400

Entitlement:    Owner
```

Request:

```
POST /accounts/345/password HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8

newPassword
```

Response:

```
Status Code: 201 Created
```

**My code:**

```
 @response = RestClient::Request.new(
:method => :post,
:url => 'https://zomgo.de:7849/server/rest/accounts/50s89c-a76b-475/password',
:user => 'hrums80',
:password => 'mzsdfr4',
:newPassword => 'Amerika69'
).execute
```

With this code I get the following error:

```
Http 415 unsopported media type
```

Can someone say me how I can set a new password in the request body ? And what's the meaning of that error. Thanks

Comment: What Content-Type does your RestClient set on HTTP requests?

Comment: I dont know i use the gem rest-client

Comment: I suggest you catch the HTTP request before you send it and inspect the Content-Type header. It should be set to 'text/plain'

Comment: How can i catch the request?